# How to append Http Response to a Jmeter variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to append response from set of http requests and assert response.
Example

```
Request1-> Response is "Anil"
Request2-> Response is "Sunil"
Request3-> Response is "Kumar"
Request4-> Response is "Tej"
```

I need to create a global variable "GlobalRespone". Append and store all response to this variable ex: GlobalResponse = "Anil,Sunil,Kumar,Tej"
So that I can write the custom validation rule at Request4 which will pass the Request4 if GlobalResponse contains "Sunil" or else fail the sampler.

How can we achieve this? appreciate if any one can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) at the same level as all your requests
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('GlobalRespone', (vars.get('GlobalRespone') ?: '') + prev.getResponseDataAsString())
   ```
3. Add [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the last request
4. Configure it as follows:

   [image]

The JSR223 PostProcessor will append to the variable `GlobalRespone` the response data of each Sampler in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) and the Response Assertion will check whether this variable contains `Sunil`

Demo:

[image]